# python - extend and replace if if-statement is true

Tags: python

I have a `list` of `tuples` and I just want to make a simple nested loop that has a if-statement and if it´s `True` it should replace the existing tuple in the list. I have made so that it writs both the new tuple and the old tuple, i can´t get rid of the old tuple.

```
 list_byte = [(1, 1, 0, '0x1636'), (1, 1, 1, '0x19'), (1, 1, 2, '0x02'), (1, 1, 3, '0x2F'), (1, 2, 0, '0x1637')]
result = (2, '0x02', 'LEV'), (2, '0x19', 'RD'), (2, '0x1636', 'IMG'),(2, '0x1637', 'IEM')

 t = []
    for x in list_byte:
        print(x)
        for y in result:
            #print(y)
            if y[:2] == x[2:]:
            #print(y[:2],'-')
                t.extend([x+y[1:]])
        t.append(x)
```

how it print now:

```
(1, 1, 0, '0x1636', '0x1636', 'IGM')
(1, 1, 0, '0x1636')
(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '0x19', 'RD')
(1, 1, 1, '0x19')
(1, 1, 2, '0x02', '0x02', 'LEV')
(1, 1, 2, '0x02')
(1, 1, 3, '0x2F')
(1, 2, 0, '0x1637', '0x1637', 'IEM')
(1, 2, 0, '0x1637')
```

I tried using else: after the if but then the loop get crazy and prints every value in a strange sequens...this is the closet i have gotten.

how i want it how it print now:

```
(1, 1, 0, '0x1636', '0x1636', 'IGM')
(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '0x19', 'RD')
(1, 1, 2, '0x02', '0x02', 'LEV')
(1, 1, 3, '0x2F')
(1, 2, 0, '0x1637', '0x1637', 'IEM')
```

Comment: What do `list_byte` and `result` look like? (You have these two variables in the code - would be handy to know what they look like. Would be grand if you could provide simple samples)

Comment: sure thing (look edit) @Atlas7

Comment: this is just some of the tuples in this list, but i hope it shows how it looks @Atlas7

Comment: Ah. I think I know what you are trying to achieve. Some kind of "joining", using the 3rd element of each `list_byte` tuple as primary key, join against the 2nd element of `result`, and display accordingly.

Comment: yeah, sort of! I get the "joining" part but not how to remove/replace the joined elements in the new list "t"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149730/discussion-between-atlas7-and-sesar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this code running after some experiments. Written in Python 3.6. (If you are on Python 2.x just replace `print(i)` with `print i`.

## Revised Code

```
list_byte = [(1, 1, 0, '0x1636'), (1, 1, 1, '0x19'), (1, 1, 2, '0x02'), (1, 1, 3, '0x2F'), (1, 2, 0, '0x1637')]
result = (2, '0x02', 'LEV'), (2, '0x19', 'RD'), (2, '0x1636', 'IMG'),(2, '0x1637', 'IEM')

t = []
for x in list_byte:
    line = x
    for y in result:       
        if y[1] == x[3]:
            line = x + y[1:]
    t.append(line)

for i in t: print(i)
```

## Console Output:

```
(1, 1, 0, '0x1636', '0x1636', 'IMG')
(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '0x19', 'RD')
(1, 1, 2, '0x02', '0x02', 'LEV')
(1, 1, 3, '0x2F')
(1, 2, 0, '0x1637', '0x1637', 'IEM')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list of tuples and I just want to make a simple nested loop that has a if-statement and if it´s True it should replace the existing tuple in the list

Is the following minimal example what you want?

```
mylist = [(1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c')]
print(mylist)
for it in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[it][1]=='b':
        mylist[it] = (42, 'foo')
print(mylist)


>> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
>> [(1, 'a'), (42, 'foo'), (3, 'c')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xCsMwDER3f4U2yeAlSaeCv8R4SEvcClI5uFry9a4bEwq96bh33G27PrNMtZrXvvJbwUOgweGM1gGNDm@HmRze0UazFRalXrUm5QKswAJllsdC6yIns1cDTZygB4E1hiF63wY7@urH2i9dRgeYckb791PrBw)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)?

Like so:

```
for i in filter(lambda x: x in [y for y in result if y[:2] == x[2:]] , list_byte):
    print(i)
```

Basically, the lambda function returns true if your tuple is found in the `result` meeting your condition `y[:2] == x[2:]`

Might need some adjustments to make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
list_byte = [(1, 1, 0, '0x1636'), (1, 1, 1, '0x19'), (1, 1, 2, '0x02'),(1, 
1, 3, '0x2F'), (1, 2, 0, '0x1637')]
result = (2, '0x02', 'LEV'), (2, '0x19', 'RD'), (2, '0x1636', 'IMG'),(2, 
'0x1637', 'IEM')
t = []
for x in list_byte:
    for y in result:
        if y[:2] == x[2:]:
            x = x + y[1:]
    t.append(x)
```

Tried to make this as close to the original code as possible.  Hope this helps!